# Resize listbox depending on length of content

Tags: wpf, listbox, resize

Hey I want a WPF listbox to change the width depending on the length of the content.
So there is no scrollbar.

Would be awesome if the size of the Grid and MainWindow would change also.

Is there a way to the size of a string. not the normal length? idk
Or can you detect if the scrollbar is visible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trivial to achieve if the listbox is the only thing in your window:

```
    Height="300"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    SizeToContent="Width"
    >
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item That is wider</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #3</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Do not set width on the window.

Set SizeToContent="Width" on the window.

It will then size to the longest string in your listbox.

If you have a more complicated layout, it's a little more complicated.

Say your window ( or perhaps the container the listbox is in ) was a fixed or minimum width.

You can set horizontal alignment and content alignment on the listbox.

Here, I've made the grid pink so you can see the listbox extent

```
    Height="300"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    SizeToContent="Width"
    >
<Grid Background="Pink"
      MinWidth="600">
    <ListBox Width="Auto"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
             >
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item That is wider</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>ListBox Item #3</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```